# Vuejs - Excel download with REST

Tags: excel, rest, file, vue.js, download

I'd like to download a Excel per REST call. If I use Postman to test the endpoint it works fine. But if I start the request on my website the respons is ok but I have no idea how i can change de response to a Excelfile download.

Here is my code:

```
  async export () {
  const data = await generateExport()
  const blob = new Blob([data], {
    type:
      'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
  })
  require('downloadjs')(
    blob,
    'FileName_' +
      new Date().toLocaleDateString() +
      '.xlsx',
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
  )
}
```

OR

```
    async export () {
  var data = await generateExport()
  require('downloadjs')(
    data,
    'FileName_' +
      new Date().toLocaleDateString() +
      '.xlsx',
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
  )
}
```

Thank you for your answer
Best wishes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: You can use this library if your REST call returns data in JSON format - https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-json-excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I used downloadjs as ES6. After a while, I saw, that the server response was not only the file. It was in a container which also was named data. Now I simply navigated in the object to the source.

```
import * as download from 'downloadjs'
```

...

```
var data = await generateExport();

download(
    data.data,
    'NameOfTheFile_' + new Date().toLocaleDateString() + '.xlsx',
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml'
  )
```

Comment: @anothernode see the solution above